# Why does everyone want to kill me everywhere I go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

What can I do if everyone in every place I go wants to kill me? I'm a vampire, could that be the reason?

I can't go anywhere or do any quest because people won't let me be EVERYWHERE.

Comment: Do you have the Dawnguard DLC?

Answer (score 12):

In vanilla Skyrim, if a vampire player goes 3 in-game days without feeding then they're regarded as hostile by all NPCs. So you can either feed on a human or cure your Vampirism. Another option, if your character is strong in Illusion magic, is to cast Pacify to stop the NPCs. Be warned that some Expert level NPCs won't be affected without the Kindred Mage perk if you choose that route though. Then you'll be able to go places and do things.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to feed or cure your Vampirism. I had the same exact problem as you did. I didn't know you had to feed.